# Regex: Word with parenthesis (out and in)

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get word within and outside of the parenthesis. How can I solve this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "id int(100) not null";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+(.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
```

This gives me output `id int(100)`. However I need just `int(100)` as output.

More examples:

- `name varchar(100) not null` should give output of `varchar(100)`.
- `showMenu tinyint(1) null default '0'` should give output of
  `tinyint(1)`.

Comment: I'm looking at several edits to the answers below and I don't think they're still right.  You need a parser to do a proper job of this, and I don't think getting ahold of a SQL parser would be that hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\(.*?\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

is what you need. Match word chars followed by a literal bracket, x chars and then closing literal bracket

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for ! . I missed a small bit.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, attempts; you could try following regex. This will create 1 capturing group by which you could get the matched value.

```
\b(\S+\([^)]*\))\s*\b
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/w1q9dt/1)

***Explanation:*** Simply matching `\b` word boundary followed by a capturing group, which is matching all non-spaces 1 or more occurrences till ( comes then match everything till 1st occurrence of ) close capturing group; followed by 0 or more occurrences of spaces followed by word boundary.

Comment: Very good. Just a minor improvement: I would not create a capturing group unless I need one i.e. I would use `\b(?:\S+\([^)]*\))\s*\b`.

Answer (score 2):

The [regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/QnKi94/1), `\w+\s*\(\s*.*\s*\)` meets your requirement.

**Explanation:**

- `\w+`: 1+ `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` characters
- `\s*`: 0+ whitespace characters
- `\(`: Literal, `(`
- `.*`: 0+ characters (any)
- `\)`: Literal, `)`